# Qt: How to properly define the signal argument for this code?

Tags: qt, arguments, parameter-passing, signals-slots

I am using Qt 4.8 on Ubuntu 14.04.
Currently, I have the following piece of code:

```
void MyServer::processMessage()
{
   QByteArray data;
   ...

   ...
   emit newMessage(data);
}
```

--
What would be the proper way to define the `newMessage` signal (in the header file):

```
signals:
    void newMessage(const QByteArray & newData);
```

or:

```
signals:
    void newMessage(QByteArray newData);
```

As seen above, the signal is emitted right before exiting the `processMessage` function, so the `QByteArray data` won't exist anymore immediately after emitting that signal...
So, my worries about the first way of defining the signal is that it passes as an argument a reference to an object (instance) that doesn't exist anymore after `newMessage` is emitted.

Thanks in advance for your time and patience!
BTW: My app is single-thread.
PS: Would things differ if app would be multi-threaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are ok, though the most common version would be

```
signals:
    void newMessage(const QByteArray &newData);
```

Regarding your worries about your first option: passing a reference can only be done with `Qt::DirectConnection` (which `Qt::AutoConnection` bascially results in for a single threaded signal/slot connection), as the others require that signal arguments are storable in `QVariant` and references aren't.

With such a `Qt::DirectConnection` the emit will "return" when all slots connected to the signal have been executed.
So at this point nobody will need the `data` object anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the previous answer '[how to pass qobject as argument from signal to slot in qt connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025182/how-to-pass-qobject-as-argument-from-signal-to-slot-in-qt-connect)', it is recommanded to pass Object as pointer.

So, the signals declaration is:

```
signals:
    void newMessage(QByteArray* newData);
```

And the emission of signal is:

```
void MyServer::processMessage()
{
   QByteArray data;
   ...

   ...
   emit newMessage(&data);
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, QObject cannot be copied and hence cannot be passed by value... now that you mentioned QObject :)

Comment: Anyway, pointer or reference - it doesn't matter too much for me (as long as I don't have to pass the data object by value). After all, a reference can be seen as a constant pointer with automatic indirection (i.e. the compiler puts the * operator for you).

Comment: please don't do that, this exactly results in the issue the OP was worrying about (if the connection type was `Qt::QueuedConnection`). `QObject`s are usually passed by their pointer values because they can't be passed by value (they are not copyable). `QByteArray` is not a `QObject`, it is copyable, and there is really no reason for it to be passed by pointer.