# Passing object via Qt signal/slot across threads

Tags: qt, signals, qthread

I wish to pass an object using the signal/slot mechanism between threads in Qt.  Since I will be passing a pointer to the object, is it safe to call the methods on the object on the receiver's side?

According to this question [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025182/how-to-pass-qobject-as-argument-from-signal-to-slot-in-qt-connect?noredirect=1&lq=1) the object is not copied (so using original object).

Is this safe?  Or am I executing methods on an object belonging to one thread in another thread?  Is there a better way to do this?

(I have approximately 20 getters in this class so I don't want to pass individual variables, as well some of the variables are in fact pointers to objects as well)

Comment: It's not safe per se,c your have to make the passed object threadsafe by using mutexes, atomics etc. But even then you'd probably run into lifetime and ownership issues...

Comment: So signals should only send basic types (not objects)?  Qt docs say its ok (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) but don't make mention of these issues.  Any reference to Qt documentation on how to handle?

Comment: Signal/slots can be used with anything, but as soon as you share objects directly (by pointer) instead of copying them (by value/const reference), the usual multi-threading synchronization issues apply. Signal/slots are just a way to pass arguments, they don't control what happens afterwards when accessing the objects. I'd say cross-thread signal/slots are best used with values, then implementing the message-passing programming model for inter-thread communication.

Comment: @Frank: I think that's the best answer yet - if you post as reply I'll accpt

Answer (score -1):

It is not necessarily safe - signals and slots can be used to cross thread boundaries, so it's possible you could end up trying to access the object from another thread.

The thread in which the slot will be called is determined by the connection type. See [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum), but as an example:

```
connect(source, SIGNAL(mySignal(QObject*)), destination, SLOT(mySlot(QObject*)), Qt::DirectConnection);
```

In this case the function mySlot() will be called from the same thread that the mySignal() signal was emitted in. If your object is not accessed from any threads other than the same thread as the signal emitter this would work fine.

```
connect(source, SIGNAL(mySignal(QObject*)), destination, SLOT(mySlot(QObject*)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

In this case the function mySlot() will be queued, and called by the event loop of the `destination` object. So anything done to the object, would happen from within the thread running the event loop of the `destination`.

I personally find it's best to just stick to passing simple values as arguments. Even though this can work, you would need to add suitable multithreading guards to your QObject if it's likely to be accessed from multiple threads.

Comment: Question has nothing to due with GUI.  Why would "GUI based signals/slots" work ok running object in another thread, and non-GUI not?

Comment: Sorry, as Qt's a gui toolkit that's where I assume people would run into this first, but you're right it isn't necessarily so. I updated the answer to hopefully be a bit more clear

Answer (score -2):

First of all, try to use [QtConcurrent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html) when you are developing a multi-threaded application. The QtConcurrent namespace provides high-level APIs that make it possible to write multi-threaded programs without using low-level threading primitives such as mutexes, read-write locks, wait conditions, or semaphores.
After that, safety depends on your class members. If all members are thread-safe, then all will be run safely.